# hazelcast : unable to connect to any address in config

Tags: client-server, hazelcast

I have an hazelcasrCLient-xml  and have configured the port to as i have limitation on using the 5701 port :

```
<hazelcast-client>
    <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
    <network>
        <cluster-members>
            <address>135.46.61.34:28019</address>
        </cluster-members>
        <smart-routing>true</smart-routing>
        <redo-operation>true</redo-operation>
        <connection-attempt-limit>10</connection-attempt-limit>
    </network>
</hazelcast-client>
```

also for hte server side the configuration in hazelcast.xml is :

```
<hazelcast>
    <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
    <instance-name>hzpunInstance1</instance-name>

    <network>
    <port auto-increment="true">28019</port>

</network>
    <partition-group enabled="false" />
    <executor-service name="default">
        <pool-size>16</pool-size>
        <!--Queue capacity. 0 means Integer.MAX_VALUE. -->
        <queue-capacity>0</queue-capacity>
    </executor-service>
<hazelcast>
```

the server is running on cloud whereas the client in on another VM 
so when the client tries to connect to the hazelcast server i get an error :

8/18/16 10:36:23:982 GMT] 00000022 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause appServlet: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried:[/135.46.61.34:28019]
.........

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried:[/135.46.61.34:28019]....
an so on

Can anyone suggest what could be the fix or where am i  going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your config is that hazelcast nodes (server-side) are configured to use port 28019 with auto-increment option activated. So potentially, used port is anywhere between 28019 and 28119 (default value of port-count is 100).

However you client is only configured to try port 28019. There is no auto-increment option for the client, it only attempts to connect to addresses specified in the client configuration (135.46.61.34:28019 in your case)... and fails.

If you are using auto-increment for your cluster, then you must explicitly add all possible addresses int the client conf. For example:

Serverver-side config

```
<port portcount="10" auto-increment="true">28019</port>
```

Client-side config

```
<cluster-members>
    <address>135.46.61.34:28019</address>
    <address>135.46.61.34:28020</address>
    <address>135.46.61.34:28021</address>
    <address>135.46.61.34:28022</address>
    <address>135.46.61.34:28023</address>
    <address>135.46.61.34:28024</address>
    <address>135.46.61.34:28025</address>
    <address>135.46.61.34:28026</address>
    <address>135.46.61.34:28027</address>
    <address>135.46.61.34:28028</address>        
</cluster-members>
```